# How to check if Excel sheet contains activeX control?

Tags: vba, excel

I try to create a macro, placed in Workbook_Open() procedure, which adds items for combo boxes, named CBTask for **each** **sheet** in workbook, (which has combo box named CBTask in it).
Unfortunatelly following code generates Compile error: Method or data member not found"

I believe it is because **not every** sheet has CBTask in it (even on error resume next does not help). 
Is there any way to check if sheet contains combo box, so I could do the checking before trying clear it, or adding new items?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim strTaskName As String

On Error Resume Next
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.CBTask.Clear
    strTaskName = taskName(1)
    Do
        ws.CBTask.AddItem strTaskName
        strTaskName = taskName(i)
        i = i + 1
    Loop While taskName <> "LastOne"
Next ws
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

(as you can see, this code also uses additional function "taskName(intSubtaskValue as integer)" to convert integer to string (e.g. taksName(1) = "Task01", taskName(2) = "Task02...)

Comment: Since even with only one sheet the compile error is still there, the problem is not where you believed (I've no clue where it is yet).

Answer (score 2):

The `Worksheet` class doesn't have a member named `CBTask` which is why that code fails. I suggest you use the `OLEObjects` property instead:

```
ws.OLEObjects("CBTask").Object.Clear
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Rory's answer, in addition to fully qualifying your objects, you can check if an ActiveX-control of a given name exists on a worksheet by using this function:

```
Function obj_exists(obj_name As String, on_worksheet As Worksheet) As Boolean
  On Error GoTo errHandler
  Debug.Print on_worksheet.OLEObjects(obj_name).Name
  obj_exists = True
  On Error GoTo 0
  Exit Function
errHandler:
  obj_exists = False
  On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```